# Collapsing braces in Visual Studio 2013 Express IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I know there is an [extension for this in Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6c3c5dec-1534-4c42-81b1-cfd4615fd0e9). However, is anyone aware of a similar extension or setting for Visual Studio Express editions?

Something that will allow me to collapse:

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hotel.bg3))
            {
                colspan += 1;
                TableCell c3 = new TableCell();
                c3.Text = hotel.bg3.Replace(" ", "<br />");
                c3.Style.Value = "border-color: #333333;  border-width: 1pt; border-style: none none solid none; font-weight:bold;";
                c3.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                row.Controls.Add(c3);
            }
```

to:

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hotel.bg3))
            {...}
```

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the code you want to collapse and hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>** and then **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>**. You can also right click on the selection and select *Outlining > Hide Selection*. To unhide, hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>** and then **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>** or right click on the collapsed code and select *Outlining > Stop Hiding Current*.

It's also worth noting that Express editions of Visual Studio don't support extensions at all.